# Cannot save MS Word doc to PDF on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, pdf

I am going through the motions of saving as a PDF.  I do not get any error messages, but the file is simply not being written.  I have triple checked the file name and the destination directory.  It just isn't showing up.  And ideas about what I can do?

EDIT: Mac OS is Sierra.  Word is 15.30, part of Office 2016.

Comment: What versions of Word and OSX?

Comment: @jasonology  Please see edits to question.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a built in PDF export feature of Word, or are you "printing to PDF" from the standard macOS print dialog?

Comment: @Spiff  Built in PDF export.

Comment: Maybe we can get you to open the Console (in /Applications/Utilities/ ) and we can see what’s happening while you try a save as PDF.